# Exporting data using CouchbaseCLI cbexport error

Tags: database, nosql, couchbase, couchbase-lite

I tried following the documentation and used the following command for fetching the data from the travel-sample bucket in the JSON format

Command : `C:\Program Files\Couchbase\Server\bin>cbexport json -c couchbase://127.0.0.1 -u Administrator -p uity790 -b travel-sample -o F:/travel-sample.json -f lines -t 4`

But I am constantly getting this error "JSON export failed: failed to get export transferable: exporting from a collection aware cluster requires scope/collection fields to be provided" 
 
 What is the correct way of doing that using the CLI on windows?

Comment: Which version of Couchbase Server are you using?

Comment: I am using version 7.0 beta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [7.0 documentation on cbexport-json](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/7.0/tools/cbexport-json.html):

> --scope-field <scope_field> When exporting from a collection aware cluster this field will be created in each JSON document; it will be
> used to store the name of the scope the document came from.
>
> --collection-field <collection_field> When exporting from a collection aware cluster this field will be created in each JSON document; it
> will be used to store the name of the collection the document came
> from.

So it seems like you need to specify those arguments as well. Something like:

```
--scope-field couchbaseScope --collection-field couchbaseCollection
```